# Error when adding to cart 'No such entity with id = 0'

Tags: magento2, product, error, addtocart

When I add a product to my cart I get the following error:

```
No such entity with id = 0
```

This happens with every product in the store, can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Seems Session/Cookie Issue

Comment: Please check my answer, it will help you in the right direction. **@Tom**

Answer (score 7):

Please check customer_group table for "NOT LOGGED IN" group.

If its customer_group_id is not zero, truncate table

1. catalog_product_index_price and
2. catalog_product_index_tier_price.

Then run following query.

```
UPDATE `customer_group` SET customer_group_id = 0 WHERE customer_group_code='NOT LOGGED IN';
```

Answer (score 2):

Please check `customer_group` table in Magento2 database.

Check **NOT LOGGED IN** value in `customer_group_code` field. If it's not available in that field, that means the customer cannot add to cart product without **sign-in**.

And if 'NOT LOGGED IN' value available in that field then set its`customer_group_id` '0'.

First, you need to sign-in and then Add to Cart.

This work for me properly. I hope this will help you.

Answer (score 2):

I had missing [General group](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-groups.html) with id = 1 in the customer_group table. After adding of the group, products started to get added and no error message anymore.

Answer (score 1):

"This worked for me, after trying everything:

Assuming your site is in Developer Mode, you can change it to Production Mode, clear/flush cache and then switch back to Developer Mode."

THIS WORKED FOR ME IT'S LIFE SAVER! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, after trying everything:

Assuming your site is in `Developer Mode`, you can change it to `Production Mode`, clear/flush cache and then switch back to `Developer Mode`.

I had this issue in the front end, as I recently moved the database from one server to another. I managed to solve it by doing this.