# No such entity with cartId = 0 on checkout page

Tags: checkout, customer, magento-2.2.5, customer-session

Magento2 - Customer lost session occasionally on checkout page. 
After login when I go to checkout page it's shows me below error but after refresh 4 to 5 times customer session restore again but after refresh again same issue happened.

[image]

Comment: Find similar issues [1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/171581/error-when-adding-to-cart-no-such-entity-with-id-0), [2](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5847), [3](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/6522)

Comment: Do you have using  postNL extension?

Comment: Thanks but i found the issue and resolved it, it's happening because one of my custom module.

Comment: Can you please share what you did to solve the issue? Because the Same issue I am also facing in my custom checkout module.